# Ошибка Elements() in Elements cannot be applied to:

Tags: java, android

Что мне сделать чтобы убрать эту ошибку? Записано оно в onCreate если что[image: ошибка]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listTasks = findViewById(R.id.list);

    ContentList();

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Elements Elements = new Elements();
            Elements.setName(getResources().getString(R.string.new_document));
            showDocument(Elements);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

(Elements это java файл если что)

Comment: Судя по всему нема конструктора по умолчанию. Передайте в него требуемые аргументы. И не именуйте переменные с большой буквы - компилятор может запутаться.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо

Comment: Да, и в вопросе явно не хватает проблемного кода в виде текста, не скрина и указания что это за класс - `Elements`

Comment: Добавил код onCreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто, судя по сообщению об ошибке, класс `Elements` не содержит конструктора по умолчанию, следовательно ему требуется передать все требуемые параметры, такие как name, content, дата создания (посмотрите конструктор, чтобы понять что именно этот класс требует), то есть ваш код должен быть примерно таким,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(r.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(r.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listTasks = findViewById(r.id.list);

    ContentList();

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Elements elements = new Elements("name1", "text1", new Date()); // может быть что-то еще после Date на скрине непонятно
            Elements.setName(getResources().getString(r.string.new_document));
            showDocument(elements);
            startActivity(new Intent(mainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

**P.S.** Очень не советую использовать неправильное наименования переменных (переменные по код стайлу Java должны начинаться с маленькой буквы, классы с большой, а константы только из больших букв). Иначе другие программисты запутаются, а используя выражения вроде `T<T> T = new T<T>();` вы легко запутаете даже компилятор.

Comment: что значит "запутаете компилятор"?

Comment: Значит что не стоит так писать, иначе можно долго потом разбираться, почему компилятор ругается. Скажем, если есть переменная Т и класс Т, вы можете сказать что будет вызываться при T.func() метод переменной или статистический метод класса?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin Ну это совсем другое, если компилятор ругается это значит что код не комилируется. Почему так происходит, не имеет отношение к тому, о чем вы пишете "класс Elements не содержит конструктора по умолчанию". Поскольку у вас нет описания класса Elements, вы никогда не узнаете причину ошибки.

Comment: Эээ, честно говоря, я вас не понял. Судя по скриншоту компилятор явно говорит какие параметры конструктора ему нужны. Это вполне типовая ошибка, когда переданные аргументы не совпадают с аргументами в классе.